# Can I use a fuse rated 400V 32A on a 220V 32A circuit?

Tags: fuses, ratings

Can I use a fuse rated 400V 32A on a 220V 32A circuit?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, for a fuse the amount of current (Amperes) must be the same or lower (although then it will blow more easily). The voltage must be the same or higher. So a 400V fuse can be used in an 220V application, assuming it fits properly.